# Deleting specific node of XML file

Tags: c++, xml, qt

Below I have a sample of my XML file, I want to delete a specific node in each header. How do i do it. for example in header`<HEADER>` i want to delete the node `<ADDRESS>`, not just its attribute but the whole node. in `<HEADER1>` I need to delete the attribute `<UMG_VAR Name="ABC" Value=1></UMG_var>`, here `Name` attribute is unique.

```js
<MAIN>

    <HEADER>
        <TITLE>ppc_ph_pios</TITLE>
        <AUTOR>DNL</AUTOR>
        <AGE>age</AGE>
        <SEX>Male</SEX>
        <PLACE>Earth</PLACE>
        <ADDRESS>abc</ADDRESS>
    </HEADER>
    <HEADER1>
          <UMG_VAR Name="RED" Value="3"></UMG_VAR>
          <UMG_VAR Name="ABC2" Value="2"></UMG_VAR>
          <UMG_VAR Name="ABC" Value="1"></UMG_VAR>
    </HEADER2>
    
</MAIN>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
QDomDocument doc;
doc.setContent(oldXml);

QDomNodeList nodes = doc.elementsByTagName("element");
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.count(); ++i)
{
    QDomNode node = nodes.at(i);
    QDomElement child = node.firstChildElement("child");
    if (!child.isNull() && child.attribute("id") == "0")
    {
        node.removeChild(child);
    }
}

QString newXml = doc.toString();
```